# Loading html file from local folder into Webview Android apps

Tags: android, html, webview

I created an HTML simple page to open it from android apps, but when I run the apps, the WebView show only the HTML code not the design.

HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>My HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>MyHTML</h1>
<p>Hello!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

in the OnCreate in MainActivity:

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

The WebView show all the HTML code above.

Comment: What about removing the unnecessary `<!DOCTYPE html>` line?

Comment: @Funkystein thnx, I removed it but No effect

Comment: Apparently, it's the only anomaly. I also load my html files from a folder placed in `/assets`. Something like this: `pgHelp = "file:///android_asset/help/help-" + CLS_Cfg.lang + ".htm";`. Then I load it the same way you do (after tinkering a bit with the WebView settings, for faster loading).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem
just open index.html from eclipse with text Editor then save all and try